# FxCop: custom rule for checking assembly info values

Tags: c#, fxcop, fxcop-customrules

Is there a reasonably simple way to get FxCop to check that all my assemblies declare a particular attribute value? I want to make sure everyone has changed the default you get on creating a project:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft")] // fail

[assembly: AssemblyCompany("FooBar Inc.")] // pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a pretty easy rule once you know that FxCop's "largest" analysis target is a module, not an assembly.  In most cases, there is one module per assembly, so this won't pose a problem.  However, if you are getting duplicate problem notifications per assembly because you do have multiple modules per assembly, you can add a check to prevent generating more than one problem per assembly.

At any rate, here's the basic implementation of the rule:

```
private TypeNode AssemblyCompanyAttributeType { get; set; }

public override void BeforeAnalysis()
{
    base.BeforeAnalysis();

    this.AssemblyCompanyAttributeType = FrameworkAssemblies.Mscorlib.GetType(
                                            Identifier.For("System.Reflection"),
                                            Identifier.For("AssemblyCompanyAttribute"));
}

public override ProblemCollection Check(ModuleNode module)
{
    AttributeNode assemblyCompanyAttribute = module.ContainingAssembly.GetAttribute(this.AssemblyCompanyAttributeType);
    if (assemblyCompanyAttribute == null)
    {
        this.Problems.Add(new Problem(this.GetNamedResolution("NoCompanyAttribute"), module));
    }
    else
    {
        string companyName = (string)((Literal)assemblyCompanyAttribute.GetPositionalArgument(0)).Value;
        if (!string.Equals(companyName, "FooBar Inc.", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            this.Problems.Add(new Problem(this.GetNamedResolution("WrongCompanyName", companyName), module));
        }
    }

    return this.Problems;
}
```