# Code Analysis AssemblyNode.GetType always returns null

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I am writing custom Code Analysis rules for Visual Studio 2010 (basically FxCop but the newest version). I am trying to get an attribute (or, a collection of all the attributes) applied to the assembly being checked, using code like the following:

```
public override ProblemCollection Check( ModuleNode module )
{
    AssemblyNode assembly = module as AssemblyNode;
    if ( assembly != null )
    {
        Identifier ns = Identifier.For( "System.Reflection" );
        Identifier attr = Identifier.For( "AssemblyCopyrightAttribute" );
        TypeNode type = assembly.GetType( ns, attr );         
        ...
```

...but 'type' is always null, even when I know for fact that such an attribute is defined for the assembly.

Furthermore... when I debug this, I see that the assembly.ModuleAttributes collection is empty, as is ExportedTypes, as is Modules... it looks as though the assembly contains nothing at all! However, the 'base' ModuleNode is fully populated, and for example does contain 14 Attributes in its attribute collection.

It's as though "module as AssemblyNode" is wrong, but if so it would return null! Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleNodel.GetType` looks for *definition* of the type, not *use* of the type.  AssemblyCopyrightAttribute is defined in the mscorlib assembly, which is probably not what your rule is targeting.  To find uses of AssemblyCopyrightAttribute, try using `assembly.GetAttribute` instead.  For an example, see [FxCop: custom rule for checking assembly info values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091821/fxcop-custom-rule-for-checking-assembly-info-values).