# If type has StructLayoutAttribute then return in fxcop

Tags: c#, code-analysis, fxcop

I am writing a custom FxCop (Code Analysis) rule using the FxCop API.

What I want to achieve is the following:

1. Find fields which have as declaringtype a Struct.
2. If the struct has a "StructLayoutAttribute", ignore the field.
3. If the field is not read-only, add a new problem.

The basics are working correctly, I just can't seem to figure out how to check if the declaringtype has the StructLayoutAttribute or not.

It so happens that the StructLayoutAttribute is not defined in the FxCop API. How would I go about finding it then?

Some sample(C#)-code:

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
{
    Field field = member as Field;
    if (field == null)
        return null;
    if (field.DeclaringType.NodeType != NodeType.Struct)
        return null;        
    //Possibly something like: if(field.DeclaringType.Attributes .....
    // return null;
    if (!field.IsInitOnly)
    {
        Resolution resolution = GetResolution(field, field.DeclaringType);
        Problems.Add(new Problem(resolution));
    }
    return Problems;
}
```

Addition: This should get ignored.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MXRecord
{
    public IntPtr Next;
    public string Name;
    public short Type;
    public short DataLength;
    public int Flags;
    public int Ttl;
    public int Reserved;
    public IntPtr NameExchange;
    public short Preference;
    public short Pad;
}
```

And this should NOT.

```
private struct MXRecord
{
    public IntPtr Next;
    public string Name;
    public short Type;
    public short DataLength;
    public int Flags;
    public int Ttl;
    public int Reserved;
    public IntPtr NameExchange;
    public short Preference;
    public short Pad;
}
```

What I tried (as suggested) is the following:

```
StructLayoutAttributeType = FrameworkAssemblies.Mscorlib.GetType(Identifier.For("System.Runtime.InteropServices"),Identifier.For("StructLayoutAttribute"));

Field field = member as Field;
if (field == null)
    return null;
if (field.DeclaringType.NodeType != NodeType.Struct)
    return null;
AttributeNode structLayoutAttrib = field.DeclaringType.GetAttribute(StructLayoutAttributeType);

if (structLayoutAttrib != null)
    return null;
if (!field.IsInitOnly)
{
    Resolution resolution = GetResolution(field, field.DeclaringType);
    Problems.Add(new Problem(resolution));
}
return Problems;
```

Comment: Sure, check for the attribute.  Pretty unclear what the hangup might be, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091821/fxcop-custom-rule-for-checking-assembly-info-values) for a similar example.

Comment: This is not at all what I am searching for; the attribute is not declared at assembly level. I will edit my question with extra data to show you.

Comment: Well, sure, kinda obvious.  So don't use module.ContainingAssembly.GetAttribute(), use field.DeclaringType.GetAttribute().  Since you want to check the attribute on the struct.  It is very unclear what you've tried to make this work.

Comment: I have tried such a construction. The problem is, however, that the StructLayoutAttribute is not defined in the FxCop API, so how would I go about testing for it then?

Comment: AssemblyCompanyAttribute is also not defined in FxCop, use the same construct as in the linked answer but for System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute.  Also in mscorlib.

Comment: Do I put "System.Runtime.InteropServices" in the first Identifier, and "StructLayoutAttribute" in the second? I am not sure how to handle this.

Comment: I tried your suggested way, and it did not work. Updated example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems here.  The first is with your use of the field's `DeclaringType` property instead of its `Type` property.  `DeclaringType` refers to the type in which the field is declared, which doesn't seem to be what you want to examine.  For example, in

```
public class Foo
{
    private Bar _bar;
}
```

`_bar`'s `DeclaringType` is `Foo`, but its `Type` is `Bar`.

Unfortunately, fixing this won't resolve the bigger problem, which is that `StructLayoutAttribute` is a special attribute that doesn't actually make it into the generated IL as a custom attribute.  The compiled struct will always be marked as having a sequential, explicit, or auto layout, but this is done using the type header, not by conserving the `StructLayoutAttribute` in the IL.  If the source code did not include a `StructLayoutAttribute`, the compiled struct will be marked as having a sequential layout.

What this ultimately means for your rule is that it can't be written against the IL unless what you actually care about is the kind of layout as opposed to the presence of the attribute.  If the presence of the attribute really is relevant to you, a tool that examines the source code (e.g.: StyleCop) would be a more suitable choice.

Comment: Thank you Nicole! I had indeed seen the flags being added with either SequentialLayout, AutoLayout or ExplicitLayout. As for targeting the DeclaringType is exactly what I want to examine; I want to examine the fields inside a struct, but if that struct is marked with the attribute, I want the fields inside the struct to be ignored. As you said actually discovering the attribute is not possible; but the use of DeclaringType is appropriate here. Anyways, thanks again for the info!